# Use Gson parse json in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Testing process ，a few mobile phones occurs classcastException for class TecomPPAccount,but most work well.Please help me see the code where are not correct?

**The LogCat ouput:**

message = {"1000.11.1220.244.407":{"alias":"","username":"108","password":"108","secondIP":"192.168.0.102","isRegister":true}}

> 04-14 15:56:50.979 E/Parcel (26701): Reading a NULL string not
>   supported here.
>
> 04-14 15:56:50.989 I/TAG ( 4837):
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   com.teco.powercloud.network.TecomPPAccountInfo
>
> 04-14 15:56:50.989 W/System.err( 4837): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to
>   com.teco.powercloud.network.TecomPPAccountInfo
>
> 04-14 15:56:50.989 W/System.err( 4837): at
>   com.teco.powercloud.network.TecomPPManager.loadAccountInfos(TecomPPManager.java:830)
>
> 04-14 15:56:50.989 W/System.err( 4837): at
>   com.teco.powercloud.network.TecomPPManager.init(TecomPPManager.java:852)
>
> 04-14 15:56:50.989 W/System.err( 4837): at
>   com.teco.powercloud.MainPageActivity.onCreate(MainPageActivity.java:80)

**1.The below method is to parse json to a map object or parse a map object to json:**

```
public static synchronized  void putMapGson(SharedPreferences shaPre,String shaPreKeyName,@Nullable ConcurrentHashMap<String,TecomPPAccountInfo> map){  

    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(map);
    Log.e("Test", "putMapGson str = " + jsonStr);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shaPre.edit();
    editor.putString(shaPreKeyName, jsonStr);
    editor.commit();
}  

@SuppressWarnings({ })
public static synchronized  ConcurrentHashMap<String,TecomPPAccountInfo> getMapGson(SharedPreferences shaPre,String shaPrekeyName){  
    String message  = shaPre.getString(shaPrekeyName,"");  
    Log.e("Test", "message = " + message);
    try {
        if (!"".equals(message)) {
            TypeToken<ConcurrentHashMap<String,TecomPPAccountInfo>> token = new TypeToken<ConcurrentHashMap<String,TecomPPAccountInfo>>() {};
            return gson.fromJson(message,token.getType());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<String,TecomPPAccountInfo>();  
}
```

**2.The TecomPPAccount.java content:**

```
public class TecomPPAccountInfo implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Expose
    private String username;
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @Expose
    private boolean isRegister;
    @Expose
    private String secondIP;
    @Expose
    private String thirdIP;
    @Expose
    private String alias;

    public TecomPPAccountInfo() {
        super();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isRegister() {
        return isRegister;
    }

    public void setRegister(boolean isRegister) {
        this.isRegister = isRegister;
    }

    public String getSecondIP() {
        return secondIP;
    }

    public void setSecondIP(String secondIP) {
        this.secondIP = secondIP;
    }

    public String getThirdIP() {
        return thirdIP;
    }

    public void setThirdIP(String thirdIP) {
        this.thirdIP = thirdIP;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the LogCat output tell you everything? For starters  `Reading a NULL string not supported here.` for input `message = {"1000.11.1220.244.407":{"alias":"","username":"108","password":"108","secondIP":"192.168.0.102","isRegister":true}}` where it looks to me like `"alias"` is the culprit.

Comment: focus on this : "04-14 15:56:50.989 W/System.err( 4837): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.teco.powercloud.network.TecomPPAccountInfo"